Topological Spaces Homeomorphic to Uncountably Infinite Disjoint Union and Products of itself
There are many of topological spaces $(X,\mathcal T)$ such that $X\cong X\sqcup X$ and $X\cong X\times X$.
For the Cantor space $\mathcal C$, it is also true that it is homeomorphic to countable product and finite disjoint union of itself (Product of countably many Cantor sets). So are the countable product of some discrete spaces, provided that they are large enough.
However, I am trying to characterise the topological spaces $(X,\mathcal T)$ such that
$$X\cong\prod_{\kappa}X$$
and
$$X\cong\coprod_{\kappa}X$$
for fixed cardinal number $\kappa$. In the countable $\kappa=\omega$ case, a standard example $\mathcal C=\{0,1\}^\omega$ is given by the countable product of discrete spaces.
Are there less trivial examples of topological spaces satisfying the given conditions (possibly, a not-very-discrete space)?
I see that for each $\kappa$, $\kappa^\kappa$ where the base $\kappa$ is of discrete topology will do.

${0,1}^\omega$ is not homeomorphic to $\coprod_{\omega}{0,1}^\omega$ because the former is compact and the latter isn't.

An example that I think is correct is the Baire space $\Bbb N^{\Bbb N}$. Is that what you meant?

For general $\kappa$, I don't see immediately why a countable product will do, but I think $\kappa^\kappa$ will do. The key point is that $\coprod_\kappa X \cong \kappa \times X$. If $X$ is any topological space, then $X^\kappa \times \kappa^\kappa$ also has your property (where the $\kappa$ at the bottom has the discrete topology), which is slightly less trivial but works for essentially the same reason. Also: $\kappa^{\lambda_0} \times X^{\lambda_1} \times Y^{\lambda_2} \times Z^{\lambda_3}$ where $\lambda_i \ge \kappa$, and more examples of this type.

If $\kappa$ is an infinite cardinal and $X$ is any topological space, let $Y=\coprod_\kappa X$ and $Z=Y^\kappa$. Plainly $Z^\kappa=Z$. Also $\coprod_\kappa Z=Z$, since
$$Z\cong Y^\kappa\cong Y\times Z\cong(\coprod_\kappa X)\times Z\cong(\coprod_\kappa Y)\times Z\cong \coprod_\kappa(Y\times Z)\cong\coprod_\kappa Z.$$
For example, if $\kappa=\aleph_0$ and $X=\{0\}$, then $Y\cong\mathbb N$ and $Z\cong\mathbb N^\mathbb N$, the Baire space mentioned in a comment.
